# Remember selected option when page changes

Tags: jquery

I have the code bellow that shows 2 dropdowns, one for region and based on selected option, second dropdown (city) will change and show only the cities from the selected region.

This code works fine except one issue - when you make a selection like region or region + city and you apply the selection, the page refreshes and you get a new page with the results (is from osclass.org script), the selection is lost.

So, the big question here is how can i keep the selection made for region/city when page refreshes.

```
  <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true) ; ?>" method="get" class="nocsrf">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="search" />
    <h3><strong><?php _e('Location', 'theme'); ?></strong></h3>
                            <h6><?php _e('Region', 'theme'); ?></h6>
                            <?php ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions(osc_user_country()), osc_user()); ?>
                            <h6><?php _e('City', 'theme'); ?></h6>

                            <select id="sCity" name="sCity" >
                                <option value="">Any City</option>
                            </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <?php _e('Search', 'twitter') ; ?>
    </button>
```

And this is the code that populates the city select

```
                    $('#regionId').change(function updateCityList() {
                    var actualRegionId   = $(this).val();

                    if ( Math.floor(actualRegionId) == actualRegionId && $.isNumeric(actualRegionId)) {
                        /*Get cities per region*/
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>?page=ajax&action=cities",
                            data: { regionId: actualRegionId },
                            success: function( cities, err){
                                var $el = $("#sCity"),
                                    citiesOptions = {};

                                $('#sCity option:gt(0)').remove();
                                $el.val("");
                                $el.prev("span").text("Any City");
                                $.each(cities, function(key, value) {
                                  $el.append($("<option></option>")
                                     .attr("value", value.s_name).text(value.s_name));
                                });
                                $("#sRegion").attr("value", $("#regionId option[value='"+actualRegionId+"']").text());
                            },
                            dataType: "json"
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You might want to use cookies.

Comment: Can you provide a example?

Comment: [This](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) explains it quiet well.

Comment: or session storage maybe ?